# Lowrider style bent forks techniques

Tags: maintenance, repair, frames, fork, technique

[image]Would a 24 inch bent fork fit on a 20 inch frame? Is there even a 24 inch fork?  Would a 26 inch fit?  Also if it doesn't fit in could I just add to the 20 inch - would you be able to extend it making it look longer?

Comment: Please post a picture of an example of what you would like.